# sudoers shutdown tomcat in ansible

Tags: java, linux, unix, tomcat

I have tried to run the shutdown script in user2 by user1 but in vain. I have edited the sudoers file to let user1 to run the script on behalf of user2. Then i tried

`sudo -u user2 shutdown.sh` -> environment variable of user2 not detected (jave_home, jre_home)

`sudo -i -u user2 shutdown.sh` -> require my password somehow

`sudo -E -u user2 shutdown.sh` -> sorry, you are not allowed to perserve the environment

`sudo JAVA_HOME = /path -u user2 shutdown.sh` -> sorry, you dont are not allowed to set the env variables

`sudoers file: user1 ALL = (user2) NOPASSWD: shutdown.sh,startup.sh`

i have the path of my catalina home, but i am not sure which path should i add to the sudoers file before the shutdown.sh in sudoers.d

Can anyone help with this? thanks in advance.

Comment: All environment variables or shell variables required by `catalina.sh/startup.sh/shutdown.sh` can be set in a `setenv.sh` file in the same directory (by default this file does not exist). BTW: can you check your question for capitalization and spacing errors? E.g. I believe you wanted to write `sudo JAVA_HOME=/path ...`